# Microsoft Teams Card Action Launch App Tab instead of opening the page in default browser

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've been trying to develop a Bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework and have had issues finding resources on how to have a button from a MessageCard 
and/or rich card attachment open my application's tab within the Teams desktop app for Windows 10.  I've been referring to the documentation linked from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links)  and would like to know if there are any good examples to follow.  Currently the browser is launched when the button is clicked (instead of staying within the app).

The card is simplistic, however, I just need to get past this basic scenario on 
[My Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fllU6.png).  Is there way to launch the tab from the Read Article button?

[image]

**Edit / Additional Information:**

The link under the Read Article button is:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/14ec8cab-b2b7-4596-b358-a1ce962d5c7b/myAppTab?webUrl=https://myappsite.azurewebsites.net&label=News&context={'canvasUrl': 'https://myappsite.azurewebsites.net','channelId': '19:beb48ac89f9a4a329aa10e6e6da50905@thread.skype'}

The unique identifier represents the application id, the entityId persisted using the setSettings function of the Teams SDK (1.2) from was set to "myAppTab".

Comment: Can you post your deep link?

Comment: Hello Bill.  I've updated the post with a URL in the format I'm using for the button.

Comment: [Ensure that appId, entityId, entityWebUrl, subEntityWebUrl, entityLabel, subEntityLabel, and context are all URI encoded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab)

Please try this (Remove the space in https):

h ttps://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/14ec8cab-b2b7-4596-b358-a1ce962d5c7b/myAppTab?webUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmyappsite.azurewebsites.net&label=News&context=%7B'canvasUrl'%3A+'https%3A%2F%2Fmyappsite.azurewebsites.net'%2C'channelId'%3A+'19%3Abeb48ac89f9a4a329aa10e6e6da50905%40thread.skype'%7D

Comment: Thank you Wajeed!  After originally failing to get this to work based on your suggestion, I was able to finally get the query string properly URI encoded (The issue I encountered was due to how I encoded the context argument).  That is now resolved.  Your response got me going in the right direction and I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that appId, entityId, entityWebUrl, subEntityWebUrl, entityLabel, subEntityLabel, and context are all URI encoded.

Please check [Generating a deep link to your tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab) documentation.

Note: Added answer from comment for easy access.